# NextJs: Creating folder structure for /profile/username/followers path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm running `nextjs@9.2.2` and want to create a folder structure that'll support the url `/profile/username/followers` where username is dynamic.

With folder structure:

```
pages
  -- profile
     -- [username].js
```

I get the url `/profile/usrnm` where `usrnm` is a username so is it possible to have the url `/profile/usrnm/followers` and if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you can do:

```
pages
|-- profile
|   |-- [username]
|   |   |-- followers.js
|   |-- [username].js
```

This will create the url `/profile/username/followers`

Comment: Wouldn't you need the `[username]/` directory, instead of just `username/`?